# Вызов onclick в OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться и восстановить всю цепочку событий. Где вызывается метод onClick? Переопределение onClick и назначение лисенера понятно. Но облазил весь код класса view и не могу понять а как собственно происходит обработка клика на экране. Есть такое-то событие(клик), нужно вызвать метод onClick, как это в коде происходит?

Comment: Если вы ищете способ программно вызвать срабатывание слушателя нажатий, то попробуйте метод `performClick()`

Comment: вся цепочка событий - это реализация интерфейса обратного вызова (колбэк). Распространненый паттерн в Java

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо, пропустил эти методы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы недостаточно внимательно просмотрели класс View. Внутри него листенер хранится в mOnClickListener. mOnClickListener.onClick вызывается дважды, а performClick  и  callOnClick. performClick вызывается из кучи разных классов, из самого View он вызывается только в performClickInternal, который, в свою очередь, вызывается из всевозможных обоработчиков onTouchEvent. Система шлет View только поток событий TouchEvent, а вью сама определяет какой слушатель ей надо вызвать и когда

Comment: Благодарю, действительно не очень внимательно просмотрел класс View

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, Ваш вопрос заключается в том, кто инициирует вызов метода onClick для любого view на экране (вне зависимости от того, переопределен этот метод, или нет).

Для понимания этого процесса необходимо помнить, что разработка приложения под ОС Android ведется в рамках одноименного фреймворка. То есть у нашей программы (приложения) нет как таковой главной точки входа (функции main).

Каждое приложение имеет множество точек входа. Click - одна из таких точек входа. Если говорить грубо (но вполне описывая суть), то, когда пользователь нажимает на экран, СИСТЕМА Android принимает решение, был это клик, или что-то другое (касание, например).

Если система решает, что пользователь совершил click, то она находит приложение, которое сейчас на экране, по координатам click'а - view, на которую нажали, и вызывает метод onClick.

То есть вызова метода onClick в классе View Вы действительно не найдете. View должен обрабатывать это событие, но решение принимает ОС (и вызывает метод).

Как было указано в комментарии к вопросу, если необходимо программно сымитировать click, то для этого есть метод performClick().

Comment: вы в каком-то смысле правы, но уровень абстракции не так высок. Объект View получает от системы поток событий TouchEvent, и исходя из них решает, вызывать ли свой OnClickListener, OnLongClickListener или еще чего. Весь этот код можно просмотреть в классе View

Answer (score 0):

У любого View элемента можно вызвать метод setOnClickListener(), передав ему объект реализующий интерфейс слушателя OnClickListener. Далее необходимо реализовать метод(onClick) этого слушателя (то есть то что будет происходить при наступлении этого события(Клика по View элементу))

```
 view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //do something
    }
 });
```